# Show overflow menu clicking on an icon list view section header

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am creating an App where I need to display an overflow menu on clicking 
on an icon from list view section header. The list view has many sections and each section has an icon in the header. Clicking on that icon I need to show up the overflow menu/view both for IOS as well as Android

Comment: No idea how to approach this. Can you tell me

Comment: Is this an Android-native UI paradigm that you try to implement? If so, do you have an example app or Java code that does this?